# High IO rate when the system out of RAM

Tags: memory, swap, io

I found that when the system goes out of memory, the disk IO usage will be very high.

It seems many processes are **reading** from hard disk frantically (check `htop` output below). When I kill a process that use too much memory, free some memory for system. The IO usage decreases to a normal state.

The problem can be reproduced by writing a program that consumes a lot of memory until there is not enough memory on machine. When you killed that running program, everything goes back to normal.

**I am aware of the OS mechanism of swap. But it seems the swap was not even used for the whole time** (check `free` and `vmstat` output below).

```
❯ free -h
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:          859Mi       692Mi        60Mi        25Mi       106Mi        36Mi
Swap:            0B          0B          0B
```

```
❯ htop
PID   RES   SHR CPU% MEM%   TIME+    DISK READ  DISK WRITE    DISK R/W Command
 6386 37316  5380  0.7  4.2 10:40.07   14.96 M/s    0.00 B/s   14.96 M/s ahdbserver-1.3.2-SNAPSH
23252 17880 15748  0.0  2.0  0:01.24    7.91 M/s    0.00 B/s    7.91 M/s postgres -D /var/lib/po
29428   400     0  0.0  0.0  0:02.63    3.36 M/s    2.63 K/s    3.36 M/s sgagent -d
 2369  197M     0  0.0 23.0  0:01.00    1.86 M/s    0.00 B/s    1.86 M/s java -jar memtest-1.0-S
24596 10820     0  0.0  1.2  0:59.53  694.74 K/s    0.00 B/s  694.74 K/s frps -c frps.ini
22901  122M     0  2.0 14.2  1:15.23  644.74 K/s    0.00 B/s  644.74 K/s srcds_linux -game dod -
 8735  2016    52  0.7  0.2  1:46.21  344.74 K/s    0.00 B/s  344.74 K/s htop
 2959  4664   176  0.0  0.5 15:35.06  318.42 K/s    0.00 B/s  318.42 K/s tmux
23265 18160 14344  0.0  2.1  0:01.30  286.84 K/s    0.00 B/s  286.84 K/s postgres: 11/main: post
23264  7036  3992  0.0  0.8  0:00.03   78.95 K/s    0.00 B/s   78.95 K/s postgres: 11/main: Time
23262  7160  4116  0.0  0.8  0:00.04   71.05 K/s    0.00 B/s   71.05 K/
```

```
❯ vmstat 2
procs -----------memory---------- ---swap-- -----io---- -system-- ------cpu-----
 r  b   swpd   free   buff  cache   si   so    bi    bo   in   cs us sy id wa st
 1  0      0  68588   2096 103156    0    0 28436     0 1787 4288  2  8 79 12  0
 0  1      0  57564    920 115364    0    0 24604    86 1676 3811  2  4 81 14  0
 0  0      0  70252   1156 102360    0    0 31750     0 1794 4337  3  8 75 15  0
 1  0      0  68632   2776 101380    0    0 38570    16 2139 4879  2 11 67 19  0
 0  0      0  67656    892 104940    0    0 29356    14 1706 3936  3  5 77 15  0
 0  0      0  68596    372 103368    0    0 50684     0 2324 5078  3 11 70 16  0
 0  0      0  69596    268 102512    0    0 35688    38 1890 4282  2  8 76 15  0
 0  1      0  69368    172 102540    0    0 35726    54 1877 4458  2  9 71 19  0
 0  1      0  69684   1912 100916    0    0 28724     0 1759 4235  3  7 74 16  0
 0  0      0  74380    768  97076    0    0 21198     0 1484 3762  2  5 80 13  0
```

```
❯ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Debian
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)
Release:    10
Codename:   buster
```

What are the reasons?

Comment: I'll just point out that your `free -h` output indicates the system *has no* swap space to **even use**.

Comment: @rfmodulator Yes, the swap is not enabled on system.

Answer (score 3):

`iotop` will tell you which process is doing the reading.

In general the problem is due to missing cache.

Assume a process is reading the same file sequentially over and over, and that this fits in the free memory. Then you will experience no I/O: All I/O requests will be satisfied by the disk cache.

But if only 90% of the file fits in the free memory (e.g. because the free memory is too small), then suddenly *none* of the requests will be satisfied: This is because the caching algorithm uses Least Recently Used: The first 90% fits in memory, but when the last 10% is read, the first 10% is the Least Recently Used and is therefore flushed to make room for the last 10%.

When the first 10% is read again, the next 10% will be the least recently used and will therefore be flushed. And so on.

You are probably not experiencing this exact situation, but maybe your processes are reading different parts from different files again and again - thus giving a similar result.

Answer (score 0):

Not only disk cache can be evicted from memory.

The kernel can evict the pages of running applications to leave only the ones which are currently running. This might create a huge amount of IO for "fat" applications which have a lot of code to run.